# Adding an int to all elements of a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, addition, stdvector

I have a vector with integers lets say `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.

How can I add a constant value `10` to each element to modify the vector to be `{11, 12, 13, 14}`.

And the same thing with divides if I wanted to divide each element by an `int` and modify the vector. I haven't been able to find solutions.

Comment: Read about [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a vector? If you don't there isn't much point in having a vector.

Comment: im trying to do this in one line. I am using transform which can add all elements of one vector by elements of another vector. but I cant find a way which will add all to all elements of a vector by a constant amount.

Comment: "I haven't been able to find solutions" I find that difficult to believe. What resources did you look at? Was there anything that came close? Did you try it? What happened when you did? This is a pretty basic operation.

Comment: Please post your full source code so we can help figuring out whats going on also take a look at the answers below and mark one of them as the answer to help feature readers.

Answer (score 5):

> Lets say `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, how can I **add a constant value `10`** to each
>   element to modify the vector to be `{11, 12, 13, 14}`. and the same
>   thing with **divides** if [...]

### How about using [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)!

> `std::valarray` is the class for representing and manipulating arrays of
>   values. It supports **element-wise mathematical operations** and various
>   forms of generalized subscript operators, slicing and indirect access.

If you can use them, that is just one line of operation. **([See a live demo online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t4425EIqkqIwdIJv))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray> // std::valarray

int main()
{
   std::valarray<int> valArray{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   valArray += 10;  // add each element with 10
   for (const int ele : valArray) std::cout << ele << " ";
   std::cout << "\n";

   valArray /= 2;   // divide each element by 2
   for (const int ele : valArray) std::cout << ele << " ";
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
11 12 13 14 
5 6 6 7
```

Answer (score 4):

There is many ways you can achieve what your aiming for, but I will post the 2 most used of them.

**Solution 1 :**
You have to use iterators to solve your underlying problem.
In the code just below I'm iterating through all the references of the elements of my vector and modifying their values.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};

  for(int& x : vec) // if you want to add 10 to each element
    x += 10;

  for(int& x : vec) // if you want to divide each element
    x /= 2;

  for (int x : vec) // print results
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Use the [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) function provided by the standard library (STL) in the header algorithm. Which also boils down to using iterators but in this solution you only have to write one line.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // you need to include this to use std::for_each() !

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int &n){ n+=10; }); // add 10 to each element
  std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int &n){ n/=3; }); // divide each element by 3
  for (int x : vec) // print results
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `transform`:

```
  std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::transform(
          v.begin(), v.end(),             // The input source
          v.begin(),                      // The output destination
          [](int x) { return x + 10; }    // The transforming function
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

… or, if you don't want to write the loop yourself:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [](int& x) { x += 10; });
```

But the loop is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Or simply with just a for loop, like:

```
for (auto& item : vec)
{
    item += 10;
}
```

But I admit that for_each looks better...